# Simple (classical, non-damped) 1D harmonic oscillator - how to represent phase space elliptical trajectory in polar form for an ellipse?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Considering a classical, non-damped 1D harmonic oscillator (e.g. mass $m$ oscillating along $x$-axis attached to spring with constant $k$) -- described by Hamiltonian (for constant energy $E$) $$E=p^2/2m + kx^2/2,$$ which system follows an elliptical trajectory in corresponding phase space $(p, x)$:

I want to formulate an equation for this phase space trajectory in polar form for an ellipse (origin at ellipse center), having semi-major/minor axes $a/b$, using the standard polar form:

$$r(θ)=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{(b\cos(θ))^2 + (a\sin(θ))^2}}$$

***I am stumped as to what "a" and "b" would be in terms of "m", "k" and "E".  Can you suggest what they might be?***

It seems that, in general, the square of the radius of the ellipse would be in units of energy (kg-m^2/s^2), so I'm trying to find what "a" and "b" would be such that r^2(theta) would thus be in units of energy.  ***Or am I incorrect in assuming that $r^2(\theta)$ would be in units of energy?***

Any insights/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Al ellipse doesn't have a 'center': it has two focal points. Similarly, it has no radius...

Comment: OK, my mistake for not describing correctly.  I meant to convey as described here (with "center" on semi-major axis half way twixt focal points):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center

Comment: OK, that's been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to suggest. Simply write your equation in terms of dimensionless quantities/ratios:
$$
1= \frac{x^2}{2E/k}+ \frac{p^2}{2Em}~~\leadsto \\
a=\sqrt{2E/k}, ~~b=\sqrt{2Em}.
$$
This is to say now, that the semimajor axis, *a*, is in units of length and the semi minor one, *b*, in units of momentum. Assuming neither vanishes or blows up, if you measure *x* in units of *a*, and *p* in units of *b*, you really have a circle.

If you measure space-amplitudes and momenta in fixed units, then *a* and *b* are also dimensionless numbers times these same units; this is called nondimensionalization. Giving them the same names in the polar form,
$$r(θ)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(θ)^2/a^2 + \sin(θ)^2/b^2}}~~.$$

It is then evident that $r(0)= a$, and  $r(\pi/2)= b$. There is no point in labelling the axes of the ellipse with differently dimensioned units, since quantities such as *r* are defined a bit oxymoronically, and would confuse readers who did not follow the above discussion. So, nondimensionalization is the simplest option.

---

*Edit on comment*:

No, the eccentricity is not meaningful, since the units of *x* and those of *p* are different. You may *choose* to measure *x* in m, and *p* in kg m/s,
which fixes *a=A m* and *b= B kg m/s*, in which case the pure numerical eccentricity would be
$$
e=\sqrt {1-B^2/A^2}~,
$$
but if you chose to measure *x* in 1/2 m, then *A* would be twice the previous *A* and the eccentricity would be different. The above expression for *r* has dimensionless numbers *A* and *B* instead of *a* and *b* once you've fixed your units.

So, rescaling of the abscissa or the ordinate adjust the circle to an ellipse of arbitrary eccentricity.  Conversely, the generic oscillator phase-space trajectory is always a circle, in natural units, as the standard non-dimensionalized picture yields, and bothering with ellipses is conceptually a do-nothing machine.

Comment: I think I follow your answer, in that if I make the variable substitutions, for example, X=x*sqrt(k/2E) and P=p/sqrt(2Em) I have the circle P^2+X^2=1.

In the equation for r(theta) above, I was mistaken in thinking that the units of a and b had to be the same in order to be able to add "cos^2(theta)/a^2" and "sin^2(theta)/b^2".

Is there some meaningful measure of the eccentricity (sqrt(1-b^2/a^2)) of the ellipse 1=x^2/a^2 + p^2/b^2 , even if a and b do not have the same units?

Thank you again for your help.